# QEMU / Android emulator logging system

Tags: logging, android-emulator, qemu

For weeks I've been trying to find something on the subject of logging for QEMU - specifically Android Emulator but so far I have nothing. I want to print some information regarding QEMU (Android Emulator) while emulating Android OS. I recently found out about LOGW, LOGI, etc. but to my understanding these are for logging info about Android (the emulated system) and not QEMU (the emulator itself). How do I go about changing the source of QEMU and printing the info I want? Please, it's very important!!!

Comment: Please add more details. What info do you want to print? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to print the program counter in order to see how it changes (I know about -qemu -d cpu). I haven't tried anything, because I don't know where to begin! What functions do I have to use to print something (anything)? How do I recompile the Android source? I'm in the dark here.

Comment: That is a non-trivial task, especially in case of KVM-QEmu. How many time do you want to spend on this task? Eyeballing it, I think 2 Months will get your *something*. What do you mean *exactly* when saying *program counter*? Timestep Counter? Maybe you could describe what your application is, because else I think we can't really help you. Tip: Use `ack-grep` to find stuff in the qemu source. Provide more info (say, 500-1000 words of text), then we might be able to help.

Comment: For now, I don't have a problem with time. When I say program counter I mean the emulated program counter (that points to the next block to be executed) which is not updated after every instruction, but after every branch in the emulated environment. I'm trying to figure out a bug in the core design of QEMU.

Comment: OK, I understand your issue now. Are you tied to QEMU-KVM or non-KVM? Are you referring to x86(_64) only? When do you want to print the program counter (what shall trigger the print)?

Comment: I think SO might not be the correct place to get info from. Your question is incredibly specific, so you will probably get better info from `qemu-devel`, see http://wiki.qemu.org/MailingLists

Comment: I asked at qemu-devel but I got nothing. they said to ask to Android Emulator forums

Comment: I don't know about KVM. I'm working on Android Emulator which is based on QEMU. Yes I'm referring to x86_64. I want to print the program counter after the translation of each command.